# How to calculate 95 percentile in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have used 'agg' and get average value of a column in my data frame, like this

```
df.groupBy('day','city')
  .agg(count("*"),
       avg(df.price).alias("avgPrice")
    )
```

From here [Calculate percentile on pyspark dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405449/calculate-percentile-on-pyspark-dataframe-columns),  it said I can use `df.selectExpr('percentile(MOU_G_EDUCATION_ADULT, 0.95)')` to get 95 percentile of a column.
So how can I add the that to inside the agg() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expr` function to add in `agg`.

```
(df.groupBy('city')
 .agg(count("*"),
      avg(df.price).alias("avgPrice"),
      expr("percentile(price, 0.95)").alias("percentile"))
)
```

However, as the link suggested, if your dataset is large and do not mind some approximations, consider using `percentile_approx`.

```
(df.groupBy('city')
 .agg(count("*"),
      avg(df.price).alias("avgPrice"),
      percentile_approx('price', 0.95).alias('percentile'))
)
```